# Using Python to build a special data container

Tags: python, dictionary

My english is poor.
I have a piece of json data with such a structure, and I want to use python to aggregate this data, as shown in the figure.

If the service.name is the same, then it needs to be archived, and the duplicate "url.path" needs to be removed

[image]

I don’t know what method to use to store data, use list? dict?

Can anyone help please? thanks

````
```
       {
          [
           {
            "_source" : {
              "error" : {
                "exception" : [
                  {
                    "handled" : false,
                    "type" : "Abp.UI.UserFriendlyException",
                    "message" : "未发现该用户的WeiXinUserRelation,粉丝编号447519"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "trace" : {
                "id" : "a3e3796ca145b448829d0d0f96661e67"
              },
              "@timestamp" : "2021-06-21T06:57:52.603Z",
              "service" : {
                "name" : "Lonsid_AAA_Web_Host"
              },      "url" : {
                "path" : "/product/getAAA"    }
            }
         },
           {
            "_source" : {
              "error" : {
                "exception" : [
                  {
                    "handled" : false,
                    "type" : "Abp.UI.UserFriendlyException",
                    "message" : "未发现该用户的WeiXinUserRelation,粉丝编号447519"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "trace" : {
                "id" : "a3e3796ca145b448829d0d0f96661e67"
              },
              "@timestamp" : "2021-06-21T06:57:52.603Z",
              "service" : {
                "name" : "Lonsid_BBB_Web_Host"
               },     "url" : {
                "path" : "/product/getBBB"    }
            }
         },
         {
            "_source" : {
              "error" : {
                "exception" : [
                  {
                    "handled" : false,
                    "type" : "Abp.UI.UserFriendlyException",
                    "message" : "未发现该用户的WeiXinUserRelation,粉丝编号447519"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "trace" : {
                "id" : "a3e3796ca145b448829d0d0f96661e67"
              },
              "@timestamp" : "2021-06-21T06:57:52.603Z",
              "service" : {
                "name" : "Lonsid_AAA_Web_Host"
              },      "url" : {
                "path" : "/product/getAAA"    }
            }
         }   ] }
```
````

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.  It builds a cache of all the known past names, and drops anything that is previously seen.

```py
import pprint
import json
json_data = """[
    {
        "_source" : {
            "error" : {
                "exception" : [
                    {
                        "handled" : false,
                        "type" : "Abp.UI.UserFriendlyException",
                        "message" : "未发现该用户的WeiXinUserRelation,粉丝编号447519"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "trace" : {
                "id" : "a3e3796ca145b448829d0d0f96661e67"
            },
            "@timestamp" : "2021-06-21T06:57:52.603Z",
            "service" : {
                "name" : "Lonsid_AAA_Web_Host"
            },      "url" : {
                "path" : "/product/getAAA"    }
        }
    },
    {
        "_source" : {
            "error" : {
                "exception" : [
                    {
                        "handled" : false,
                        "type" : "Abp.UI.UserFriendlyException",
                        "message" : "未发现该用户的WeiXinUserRelation,粉丝编号447519"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "trace" : {
                "id" : "a3e3796ca145b448829d0d0f96661e67"
            },
            "@timestamp" : "2021-06-21T06:57:52.603Z",
            "service" : {
                "name" : "Lonsid_BBB_Web_Host"
            },     "url" : {
                "path" : "/product/getBBB"    }
        }
    },
    {
        "_source" : {
            "error" : {
                "exception" : [
                    {
                        "handled" : false,
                        "type" : "Abp.UI.UserFriendlyException",
                        "message" : "未发现该用户的WeiXinUserRelation,粉丝编号447519"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "trace" : {
                "id" : "a3e3796ca145b448829d0d0f96661e67"
            },
            "@timestamp" : "2021-06-21T06:57:52.603Z",
            "service" : {
                "name" : "Lonsid_AAA_Web_Host"
            },      "url" : {
                "path" : "/product/getAAA"    }
        }
    }
]"""

data = json.loads(json_data)

cache = {}
for item in data:
    if item['_source']['service']['name'] not in cache:
        cache[item['_source']['service']['name']] = item

pprint.pprint(list(cache.values()))
```

Comment: hello Wes Hardaker. Thank you for your reply.
The real source data is in dict format, which I obtained from elasticsearch.
"Cache[item['_source']['service']['name']] = item" will overwrite the same data of service.name instead of increasing.
I think it should be cache[item['_source']['service']['name']] = cache[item['_source']['service']['name']] + item, but the code is wrong .

The complete pseudo code is
for item in data:
    if service.name is exists :
        cache[service.name] =  cache[service.name] + item
   else add service.name

Comment: But I still don’t know how to start writing code